# como hacer que me imprima el numero de veces el arreglo que tiene la información asignada por el usuario

Tags: javascript, loops

```
var valorTotalC = 0
var cedula = prompt("escribe tu cedula para entrar ala tienda : ");
for (cedula > 0; cedula++;) {
    var codigo = prompt("escribe el codigo del producto : ");
    var Pcant = prompt("escribe la cantidad de productos que llevaras : ");
    var precio = prompt("escribe el precio del producto : ");

    var cedula = prompt("escribe tu cedula para continuar, de lo contrario ingresa 0");

    var totalValorArt = (Pcant * precio)
    var valorTotalC = (valorTotalC + totalValorArt)

    var productos = {
        Pcant,
        precio,
        codigo,
    }
    var arreglo = [
        {
            productos
        }
    ]

    document.write("codigo del producto : " + codigo + "</br>");
    document.write("</br>");

    document.write("cantidad comprada : " + Pcant + "</br>");
    document.write("</br>");

    document.write("precio del producto : " + precio + "</br>");
    document.write("</br>");

    document.write("el valor total por articulo : " + totalValorArt + "</br>");

    document.write("</br>");
    document.write("</br>");
    document.write("</br>");


}
```

Answer (score 0):

No se entiende muy bien lo que necesitas pero puede que este te ayude:

```
var arreglo = ['pera','manzana','mango'];

for (i in arreglo){
 console.log(arreglo[i]);
}
```

esto te recorre todo el arreglo, y te imprime todos los elementos.

Comment: si es que necesito que me recorra el arreglo pero los datos del arreglo se los da el usuario como un app de compras pido codigo precio y cantidad y se repetirá hasta que sea 0 y termine y ya es que me imprima todo el recorrido que dio con los datos que dio el usuario en el arreglo que tiene todo